# html div positions and display

Tags: html

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to design a web site, using 5 different divs as shown above.

- "**A**"  is the header, ( background-image, repeat x)
- "**B**" is the navbar 1 ( image inside a div, should have 100% height )
- "**C**" is the content panel ( div, should be the only part which moves during page scroll)
- "**D**" is the footer ( div, which should be always above the "C" )
- "**e**" is the menu ( div, which should always stay at same position)

Can you help me about this, I tried but failed, and  another issue is "B","C","D" and "e" should be in the center always when resizing the window or with different screen resolutions "**x point**" and y "**point**" should resize when resizing the window.

**x point** : between left wall to "B"
 
**y point** : between C and right wall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use negative margins and float: left & right

so create a div called "container" make it the width of your minimum display.

Then do something like this

I have created this page so you can see it live, its a small version but you can adjust the widths and heights as you need.

http://luistovar.com/divs.html

```
<center>
<div id="container">

    <div id="a"><font color="white">A</font>
        <div id="e"><font color="white">E</font></div><!-- div e end -->
    </div><!-- div a end -->

    <div id="b"><font color="white">B</font></div><!-- div b end -->

    <div id="c"><font color="white">C</font></div><!-- div c end -->

    <div style="clear:right"></div><!-- clear end -->

    <div id="d"><font color="white">D</font></div><!-- div d end -->

</div><!-- container end-->
</center>
```

Now for your CSS

```
#container {
    width:400px;
}

#a {
    width: 400px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#333333;
}

#b {
    width:80px;
    height:100%;
    margin:-30px 0px 0px 40px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#c {
    width: 250px;
    height:400px;
    margin:10px 20px 0px 0px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#999999;
}

#d {
    width: 250px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px 20px 0px 0px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#ff0220;
}

#e {
    width: 160px;
    height:30px;
    margin:10px 20px 0px 0px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#ff0220;
}
```

Adjust the widths and heights as needed
I added the background colors so you can see where the divs are landing.
I haven't tested this but it should be pretty darn close.
Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, but i have similar page right now and your page has the same problems which I don't want, I build the page with absolute position using left,top,bottom properties but works as yours, I have no problem about positioning what I want is "B" and "A" must have static position (when I scroll these areas shouldn't move), and when I resize the page (or view in different resolutions) the area between left wall(left:0) and left of "B" should resize and the "B","C","E" and "D" should always stay in the center of screen, and one more detail, when I scroll down only "C" must scroll down..

Comment: actually there are no problems but I have an image which has some parts on "A" and some parts on "B" thats why I want to give "A" and "B" static position.

Comment: are you there I think what you did now will solve my problem, but I want one more thing, "B" should have 100% height, forget about scrolling only "C" (I am talking about your link)

Comment: Hi adnanturken - sorry I had left for the day yesterday - did you get this all figured out? Let me know, msg me and I can assist.

Comment: What linux software is an option to graphically design this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the layout detailed [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm) is probably more or less what you're after. You'll want to check out absolute positioning I think for your "e" div, that's going to be the tricky one. And "B" will probably have to be z-indexed to display over the top of "A". I'd get it working though with just a 2 column layout as mentioned in the link, then add in "E" and the overlay on "B" later. Good, liquid layouts are tricky, so I wouldn't re-invent the wheel on this one.